# How to disable box-shadow globally for all Material UI components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I need to disable the default `box-shadow` for most Material UI components. Right now I'm doing this by setting the style manually for each component, like this:

```
<FloatingActionButton style={{boxShadow: "none"}} />
```

Is there a way to do this globally, maybe using a theme setting?

Answer (score 101):

You can do it by component like this:

```
<AppBar elevation={0} />
```

Comment: It does work, is it documented somewhere? How did you find out?

Comment: I think it was a guess, cause elevation applies shadows. Plus if you travel through the component typescript definitions you'll see how its props work.

Comment: It is documented at the site. the Appbar is written above the Paper component.
From the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/#appbar-api)
`The props of the Paper component are also available.`

Answer (score 34):

In the configuration object of a material-ui theme, you can see the `shadows` property, override it in your code and just leave the `none` value, remove all the rest.

You code should look like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shadows: ["none"]
});
```

All the shadow box will be removed entirely in your application.

P/s: This configuration is for version `1.0.0-beta.8`, I must note it here because this version has some breaking changes.

Comment: Hi, I'm using your solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516398/material-ui-the-shadows-array-provided-to-createmuitheme-should-support-25-elev however getting an error message :(

Comment: I got rid of the error message by doing `shadows: new Array(25)`

Answer (score 17):

I use the following for TypeScript:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import { Shadows } from "@material-ui/core/styles/shadows"

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shadows: Array(25).fill("none") as Shadows,
})
```

Answer (score 9):

**Material UI v5** update.

To disable the shadow globally, you need to reset all shadow values in the `shadows` array to `none`:

```
import { createTheme, ThemeOptions, Shadows } from '@mui/material/styles';

// create a temporary theme to get the default options
const defaultTheme = createTheme();

// get the default `shadows` object
const defaultShadows: ThemeOptions['shadows'] = [...defaultTheme.shadows];

// disable shadows
const theme = createTheme({
  shadows: defaultShadows.map(() => 'none') as Shadows,
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: why map? When you can do Array.fill

Comment: In case MUI changes the number of shadow in the future. If you're using `fill`, you can do the same with `Array(shadows.length).fill("none")`. @RajendranNadar

Comment: As far as I know, there won't be a breaking change in minor or patch releases so it is safe.

Comment: @NearHuscarl I edited your original answer because of an issue with the "import" line. On MUI, anything more than a 4-level import is considered private ([Marija Najdova's answer on GitHub](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33420#issuecomment-1181433100)). Feel free to revert the changes if you dislike them, although be aware that the original answer gives an `Unexpected token 'export'` exception depending on the bundler.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `zDepthShadows` to 'none' in the theme, either by creating a custom theme, or overriding them when you import the theme.

Answer (score 3):

Use`<FloatingActionButton style={{boxShadow: "none"}} elevation={0} />`
Worked for me.
I actually applied it to Menu as shown below.

```
<Menu
    id="indMenu"
    onClose={handleIndustryMenuClose}
    anchorEl={anchorEL}
    open={Boolean(anchorEL)}
    className={classes.ndmenu}
    elevation={0}
    style={{
      marginTop: "3.5em",
      // boxShadow:"none"
    }}
  >
```

Comment: I think the question was clearly about doing it globally.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* This solution throws errors like "MUI: The elevation provided  is not available in the theme. Please make sure that `theme.shadows[24]` is defined." So probably not the best option out there.

In your [custom theme object](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/), set `shadows: "none"`:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
    
const theme = createTheme({
  shadows: "none"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Global style overrides using with createTheme function

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps:{
        disableElevation: true
      }
    },
    overwrite other components...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add shadows="none", You can also consider shadow for 1 theme and no shadow for other theme.

```
const lightTheme = createTheme({
   palette: {
      mode: "light",
      pallete:{
      ...
      },
   },
   shadows:"none",
})

const darkTheme= createTheme({
   palette: {
      mode: "dark",
      pallete:{
      ...
      },
   },
})
```

And Then in ThemeProvider

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={darkModeActive ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
     <App/>
 </ThemeProvider>
```

(Works Fine In Nextjs also!)

Answer (score -1):

Nice! add elevation={0} to success. =)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).