# Material-UI: the shadows array provided to createMuiTheme should support 25 elevations

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to get rid of shadows in the Material-UI theme.

I found this [answer here with fixed the problem](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8289). However I get the error message in the title of this question.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: red[300],
      main: red[500],
      dark: red[700]
    },
    secondary: {
      light: red.A200,
      main: red.A400,
      dark: red.A700
    }
  },
  shadows: ['none']
});
```

**Error:**

> browser.js:49 Warning: Material-UI: the shadows array provided to createMuiTheme should support 25 elevations.

I found this solution, but the answer was not helpful:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8289

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like it expects your Theme to have at least 25 shadows, in order to create the progression seen in Material UI. While I certainly don't recommend removing the shadows if you're trying to follow Material UI standards, one easy way to do it might just be to set all levels of elevation to `none`.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: red[300],
      main: red[500],
      dark: red[700]
    },
    secondary: {
      light: red.A200,
      main: red.A400,
      dark: red.A700
    }
  },
  shadows: Array(25).fill('none')
});
```

This should fulfill the requirement.

**EDIT**:

As Dave pointed out, remember to cast if you're using TypeScript:

```
shadows: Array(25).fill('none') as Shadows
```

Comment: I kept getting an error in TS, so I had to add `as Shadows` to this as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262181/4497476

Comment: @DaveHowson Correct! Important to note that this Question+Answer is JavaScript, so you'll need to `Cast` to avoid complaints by linters when using TypeScript. Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think the best way to do this is to use overrides. Depending on which box shadow you want to remove.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: red[300],
      main: red[500],
      dark: red[700]
    },
    secondary: {
      light: red.A200,
      main: red.A400,
      dark: red.A700
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      root: {
        'box-shadow':'none'
      }
    }
  }  
});
```