# Cant fully disguise Material UI Card borders

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I am trying to disguise/blend the card with the background however the tiny corners still remain exposed. I searched for hours for any solutions but non of them were working. I tried many ways to fix it like adjusting the border radius in CSS etc, but it still isn't working.

[image: Take a look:]

Here's my .CSS and .JS files:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  Select,
  Card,
  CardContent,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import InfoBox from "./InfoBox";
import LineGraph from "./LineGraph";
import Table from "./Table";
import { sortData, prettyPrintStat } from "./util";
import numeral from "numeral";
import Map from "./Map";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const App = () => {
  const [country, setInputCountry] = useState("worldwide");
  const [countryInfo, setCountryInfo] = useState({});
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [mapCountries, setMapCountries] = useState([]);
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const [casesType, setCasesType] = useState("cases");
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({ lat: 34.80746, lng: -40.4796 });
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCountryInfo(data);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCountriesData = async () => {
      fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          const countries = data.map((country) => ({
            name: country.country,
            value: country.countryInfo.iso2,
          }));
          let sortedData = sortData(data);
          setCountries(countries);
          setMapCountries(data);
          setTableData(sortedData);
        });
    };

    getCountriesData();
  }, []);

  console.log(casesType);

  const onCountryChange = async (e) => {
    const countryCode = e.target.value;

    const url =
      countryCode === "worldwide"
        ? "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all"
        : `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${countryCode}`;
    await fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setInputCountry(countryCode);
        setCountryInfo(data);
        setMapCenter([data.countryInfo.lat, data.countryInfo.long]);
        setMapZoom(4);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app__left">
        <div className="app__header">
          <h1>COVID-19 Tracker</h1>
          <FormControl className="app__dropdown">
            <Select
              variant="outlined"
              value={country}
              onChange={onCountryChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
              {countries.map((country) => (
                <MenuItem value={country.value}>{country.name}</MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="app__stats">
          <InfoBox
            onClick={(e) => setCasesType("cases")}
            title="Coronavirus Cases"
            isRed
            active={casesType === "cases"}
            cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayCases)}
            total={numeral(countryInfo.cases).format("0.0a")}
          />
          <InfoBox
            onClick={(e) => setCasesType("recovered")}
            title="Recovered"
            active={casesType === "recovered"}
            cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayRecovered)}
            total={numeral(countryInfo.recovered).format("0.0a")}
          />
          <InfoBox
            onClick={(e) => setCasesType("deaths")}
            title="Deaths"
            isRed
            active={casesType === "deaths"}
            cases={prettyPrintStat(countryInfo.todayDeaths)}
            total={numeral(countryInfo.deaths).format("0.0a")}
          />
        </div>
        <Map
          countries={mapCountries}
          casesType={casesType}
          center={mapCenter}
          zoom={mapZoom}
        />
      </div>
      <Card className="app__right">
        <CardContent>
          <div className="app__information">
            <h3>Live Cases by Country</h3>
            <Table countries={tableData} />
            <h3>Worldwide new {casesType}</h3>
            <LineGraph casesType={casesType} />
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.app__dropdown {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
}

.app__dropdown .MuiInputBase-root {
  color: #ececec;
}

.app__dropdown .MuiSelect-icon {
  color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

.app__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.app__header > h1 {
  color: #ececec;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.app__left {
  flex: 0.9;
}

.app__stats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.app__stats .MuiTypography-root {
  color: #ececec;
}

.app__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app__right .MuiCardContent-root {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
}

.app__information > h3 {
  color: #ececec;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.app__information > h3:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .app {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Comment: does seem like border-radius leaking. maybe increasing the scale a bit on the inner content would work? `transform: scale(1.1)` hacky but not tooo hacky

Comment: I've tried that just now but it just filled up half the screen.

Comment: well obviously you would you have to adjust the number properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550593/how-to-disable-box-shadows-globally-for-all-material-ui-react-components).  I think you want to say "elevation = {0}" within the component you are rendering.  In other words, I don't think it's a true border value.  I had to do this for an application in React and it worked.